# Firebase get value before onChildChange() is fired

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get old value from child in my Firebase tree before func onChildChange() is going to happen. Is it posssible? I have a lot of childs and Listener ForSingleEventValue is not my solution, so I need to focus only on event onChildChange, but I unable to catch old value from child which has been modified. Any help is welcome!
[image]

For example, I want to monitor one child "StatusEntry" and if it state is changed some func is fired within onChildChange(). But I want to get its old value.

```
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
Map<String, Object> newPost1 = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entryDate : newPost1.entrySet()) {

Map<String, Object> newPost2 = (Map<String, Object>) entryDate.getValue();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entryService : newPost2.entrySet()){

Map<String, Object> newPost3 = (Map<String, Object>) entryService.getValue();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entryTime : newPost3.entrySet()){
Map<String, Object> newPost4 = (Map<String, Object>) entryTime.getValue();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : newPost4.entrySet()){
     if (entry.getKey().equals("StatusEntry")){
     Log.e("StatusEntry",entry.getValue().toString());
     myfunction();
     }
}}}}
}
```

Comment: please put here your code

Comment: I've edit my question

Comment: Print your log by Log.d("Info",String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));

Comment: @VishalPatoliya After I made some changes I got only new value, I cannot get old.

Comment: you are storing in arraylist?

Comment: can you please .java file here?

Comment: @IvanVovk please add your current code

Comment: @adolfosrs that is all the code I have and the database. thats all. Other overrided methods I dont use. I'm changing feribase items from console to get my code working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor your code because of all this inner loops but you can get your old and new value by just setting an outer variable. How you wold do this will depend on your current implementation.

```
private String oldValue = null;

public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String newValue = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
    // your logic with old and new value
    oldValue = newValue;
}
```

Another possible solution is to keep track of your old values in a new branch of your database and retrieve it whenever the `onChildAdded` gets called.

Comment: I'm a bit frustrated. Can I get old and new value from the same datasnapshot at the same time?

Comment: @IvanVovk as far as I know this is not possible. You could also have a new branch in your database to keep track of your old values.

Comment: I thought about it and it is possible solution for me. But may be I miss something and somebody can give me interesting answer